# kendo mvvm bind text with newline to textarea

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI MVVM and trying to bind some text with newlines (`\n`, not `<br/>`) coming from server to a textarea (but the specific control is not the point here), but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div id="model">

<textarea data-ng-bind="value:myText"></textarea>

</div>
<script>

$(function () {

    var model = kendo.observable({
        myText: '@ViewData.Eval("textWithNewLines")'
    });

    kendo.bind($("#model"),model);
});
</script>
```

Server side code

```
 // GET: G4B/Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View("index", new { textWithNewLines = "text\nWith\nNew\nLines" });
    }
```

What happens here is quite obvious: the @ViewData.textWithNewLines is rendered in the page with newLine and the javascript gets broken.
[ScreenShot of the error shown in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSw45.png)

But how should I do it?

Comment: [It works fine for me if I use data-bind instead of data-ng-bind on the textarea](http://jsbin.com/pihapi/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Sorry data-ng-bind was a misspell while writing a simplified sample of my problem. You're right it was data-bind

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem rises from getting the data from server which encodes the "\n" into newLine.

The solution was to wrap my text like this:

```
<script>

$(function () {

    var oUtils = new G4BUtils();

    var model = new kendo.observable({
        myText: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData.Eval("textWithNewLines")))
    });

    kendo.bind($("#model"), model);

});
</script>
```